# How to print number only from a .json file in python

Tags: python, json

I want to print only the number from "PresentValue". But only from "ObjectIdentifier" : 1
I need to be able to specify what "ObjectIdentifier" that is going to be printed.
Here is my json file:

```
    import json 
      
    # Data to be written 
    data = {
    "AnalogValues": [
            {
                "ObjectIdentifier": 1,
                "PresentValue": 10.2
            },
            {
                "ObjectIdentifier": 2,
                "PresentValue": 20.3
            }
        ]
    }
    
    
      
    # Serializing json  
    json_object = json.dumps(data, indent = 4) 
      
    # Writing to sample.json 
    with open("AnalogValues.json", "w") as outfile: 
        outfile.write(json_object)
```

This is what I have tried so far (returns the whole json file):

```
import json 
      
    # Opening JSON file 
    with open('AnalogValues.json', 'r') as openfile: 
      
        # Reading from json file 
        json_object = json.load(openfile) 
      
    print(json_object) 
    print(type(json_object))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I am not looking for someone to "write some code for me". I will update my question with what I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function like this:

```
def get_present_value(no):
    for a in data['AnalogValues']:
        if a['ObjectIdentifier'] == int(no):
            return a['PresentValue']
    return None


print(get_present_value(2))
```

Output:

```
20.3
```